# can't compile or-tools examples on Mac due to "make: *** No rule to make target `run'."

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, or-tools

I have installed Google's or-tools on my Mac running 11.1 (Big Sur). When I run `make test_cc`, I get a long list with different results and also some messenges like `---- Integer programming example with CPLEX ---- Supports for solver CPLEX not linked in.`

However, if I try an example from https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp, I get the above error (see header) when trying to make and run the program (I have copy pasted the complete program). I have executed the make command with

`Death-Star:or-tools me$ make run SOURCE=../Routing/Routing/main.cpp`. `ls ../Routing/Routing/main.cpp` shows the file.

What have I done wrong?

or-tools version is 8.1.8487

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the file.  The error is `No rule to make target 'run'` which means that the makefile make has found has no target `run` in it.  These targets are not built into make: the makefile has to provide them.  Do you have a `Makefile`?  Does it contain that target?  Maybe you were supposed to run this from some other directory that contains the makefile, or perhaps there's some other step you have to run to generate the makefile.

Comment: Exactly, for c++ targets, the make run command only understands a set of predefined paths to point to the source file of the example.

Comment: Ok, because the documentation says `make build SOURCE=relative/path/to/program.cc` And what I also just discovered, it seems not to work with `.cpp` but only with `.cc`